# Why is the Experience Row missing in Chrome 85 Devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to access the Experience Row in DevTools to be able to measure CLS as per the new addition to Chrome here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools#cls

I can't see this row but I know there is a layout shift on the page. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: It means there was no shift detected.